# MLMultiArray in CoreML

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

This is my first time trying to us CoreML and I am a little stuck on what to do. I built a model in python with Keras and Tensorflow that would take in information from a .csv file, break down that .csv file and extract only the closing information about a stock and the date for that close. It then runs a prediction and outputs an array of forecasted prices and an array of the forecasted date. I can then use this information and plot it onto a graph. To convert this model to coreml, I imported coremltools and ran this

`mlmodel = ct.convert(model) mlmodel.save('converted_model.mlmodel')`

Which it then converted the model and outputted a .mlmodel file for my to import into Xcode. However I noticed that the input it wants to take looks like this:

[image]

I am a little confused on how I can achieve the same outcome as I did in my python model with this MlMultiarray and what it means and how I can pass it into my input below:

[image]

Sorry if it is a simple fix, I tried looking at other solutions and it did not work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check out Matthijs Hollemans' [Swiftier MultiArray](https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers/blob/master/Docs/SwiftyMultiArray.markdown)

It allows you to create a `MLMultiArray` like this:

```
var m = MultiArray<Float>(shape: [3, 4, 2])
```

And access a value like this:

```
let value = multiArray[z, y, x]
```

I've found Matthijs Hollemans' [CoreML Survival Guide](https://leanpub.com/coreml-survival-guide) very helpful. In fact, his [CoreML Survival Guide Sample](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwju1Z6m3_T2AhUfCTQIHSynD-wQFnoECCYQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsamples.leanpub.com%2Fcoreml-survival-guide-sample.pdf) has some information about `MLMultiArrays`.

If you have a more specific question I will try to help.

Comment: Hi @Jeshua, I do have the same question. My Coreml model output is `MLMultiArray`, I do not know how to extract the result from this array. could you please show me the code?

Comment: You can access the results with the second code example above: `let value = multiArray[z, y, x]`

Comment: @JeshuaLacock Do you have any idea how I can fix the output shape in my model? It is only returning MultiArray (Float32), but I need to also be structured to MultiArray (Float32 1 × 14 × 1)? I am converting  my model with this command: ct.convert(model)

Comment: @allenhinson214 if you post a question showing your conversion code I will take a look at it.